# xpath - why my query does not works?

Tags: xml, database, xpath, dtd

here is my DTD + xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE test [
  <!ELEMENT team(owner+)>
  <!ATTLIST team
    name ID #REQUIRED
    coach IDREF #REQUIRED
    >
  <!ELEMENT owner      (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT coach    EMPTY>
  <!ATTLIST coach
    name ID #REQUIRED
    >
  <!ELEMENT game    EMPTY>
  <!ATTLIST game
    teams IDREFS #REQUIRED
    winner IDREF #REQUIRED
    >
  <!ELEMENT db    (coach*,team*,match*)>
]>


<?xml version="1.0" ?> 

    <db>
        <team name = "Hapoel" coach = "Abuksis">
            <owner> Eli Tabib</owner>
        </team>
        <team name = "Maccabi" coach = "Blat">
            <owner> Shimi</owner>
            <owner> Federman</owner>
        </team>
        <team name = "Beitar" coach = "Eli Cohen">
            <owner> Arkadi</owner>
        </team>
        <team name = "ElitzorLavi" coach = "Eli">
            <owner> Zehava</owner>
            <owner> Dani</owner>
        </team>
        <coach name = "Abuksis"/>
        <coach name = "Eli Cohen"/>
        <coach name = "Blat"/>
        <coach name = "Eli"/>
        <game teams = "Hapoel Maccabi" winner = "Maccabi"/>
        <game teams = "Hapoel Beitar" winner = "Beitar"/>
        <game teams = "Maccabi ElitzorLavi" winner = "Maccabi"/>
        <game teams = "Elitzor Lavi Maccabi" winner = "Maccabi"/>
    </db>
```

i have to find the games such that number of teams is <2.
now I expect to get only the first game.
i tried this Xpath:
    db/game[count(/@teams)<2]
but it gives me all games.. what is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your xpaths. You should separate elements and attributes by `/`. `./@name` can be shortened to `@name` only. Also, if you want to get the name as the result, you have to use `/@name` at the end:

```
db/team[count(owner)>1][not(@name=//game/@winner)]/@name
```

Comment: not working yet. and it seems that for attribute you dont have to use '/'

Comment: @user2456731: You are not using standard XPath. My solution works for me.

Comment: thanks. so it was almost good. now it's interesting why it doesn't work in bit-101.com/xpath/ .

Comment: i have to find the games such that number of teams is <2. now I expect to get no game. i tried this Xpath: db/game[count(/@teams)<2] but it gives me all games.. what is my mistake?

Comment: @user2456731: By `count(@teams)`, you are not counting the real teams, you are counting the attributes named `teams`. There is one such attribute at every `game` element.

Comment: so i understand that i have to use fn:id which turns the attribute teams to list of elements. right?

Comment: @user2456731: I do not see any `id`s in the data. You would need to change `name` to `id` on `team`s.

Answer (score 0):

Q.: I have to find the teams that have more then one owner and never won a game.

Try:

```
db/team[count(owner)>1][not(@name = //game/@winner)]
```

Comment: thanks, still doesn't work. when i'm trying
db/team[count(owner)>1] i get the two teams (Maccabi & ElizurLavi)
so the problem is with no win.